# Conditional Builds (when something has changed) in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to do conditional build in Jenkins? for example every 5 mins it checks source control for new commits and will only build if there has been changes? we are using git at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up Jenkins to poll your VCS and build if there are changes but better would be to use a post-commit trigger. '[Polling must die: triggering Jenkins builds from a git hook](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)' will give you the info on setting that up.

Comment: We just went with Polling SCM trigger as its easier to set up

Answer (score 2):

I use **Build triggers -> Poll SCM** and doesn't really see the problem in using that system.

Comment: The problem is mostly with Subversion. Subversion has a pathologically stupid idea of revision IDs.